# Struggling with the intuitive picture behind the Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, radon-nikodym

I understand the math and the formal statements behind this theorem (well perhaps not), but I cannot seem to grasp an intuitive picture behind it like how one can intuitively understand an ordinary derivative as a simple rate of change. I have read through a few answers on here but most seem to focus on probability applications. Can anyone provide an intuitive picture of what is going on behind this theorem?

Comment: the intuition is that if $\mu\ll \nu$ and are $\sigma$-finite measures then $\mu$ and $\nu$ can be related by a function, that is, there is a measurable function such that $\nu(A)=\int_A fd\mu$ for all measurable $A$. This is all.

Comment: @Masacroso There is no (for lack of a better term) geometric picture behind the definition akin to a tangent line and your usual derivatives on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @CBBAM The main case where there is a nice geometric picture is when $\nu$ is such that $F(x)=\nu((-\infty,x])$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure then $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=F'(x)$ almost everywhere. The analogy for the general case is just "it's the thing you integrate with respect to $\mu$ to recover $\nu$", which is kind of like a derivative if you squint a bit. What's actually remarkable about the theorem is that all you need is for $\mu$'s null sets to be $\nu$-null, plus $\sigma$-finiteness, and then such a function exists and is essentially unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Following Masacroso's notation]

There is the common notation $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ for the function $f$ that follows the intuition that this function represents a "rate of change of the density $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$." This notation is quite suggestive, as the equation in Masacroso's comment can be written as $\int_A \, d\nu = \int_A \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \, d\mu$. Although this isn't exactly a derivative in the usual sense (since $\nu$ and $\mu$ are measures, not functions), the Radon-Nikodym derivative does have many [similar properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Properties).

In some instances the Radon-Nikodym derivative is literally a derivative of some function.
For example, if $\nu$ is some measure on the real line with distribution function $F(x) := \nu((-\infty, x])$ satisfying some condition ([absolute continuity as a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_functions)), then the Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to the Lebesgue measure is precisely the derivative of $F$, as $\nu((a,b]) = F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^b F'(x) \, dx$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: From what I understand it is one of those definitions you just have to take at face value other than the faint resemblance to a "rate of change" of measures, is this along the right line of thought?

Comment: @CBBAM Yes, don't get bogged down with the naming; there are connections with usual derivatives, but it is not literally a derivative.